# How can I create a function that outputs 'x' amount of various instances of a class?

Tags: javascript

I am creating a classic memory game with a twist. I have a card prototype and I have instances of good cards and bad cards. I would like to create a function that will deal out a spcified amount of each card. For example, I want  to deal out 16 cards: 4xammo, 4xbeers, 2xcigars,2xsnakes, 2enemigos, 2x scorpions.

I am not sure if creating instance first was the correct way to go about this or if they must be made winthin the deal function.

```
 <section class="memory-game">

 </section>

      class Card {
        constructor(name, image, health, ammo) {
          this.name = name
          this.image = image
          this.health = health
          this.ammo = ammo
        }
      }

      // Good Cards
      const ammo = new Card('ammunition', null, 1, null),
            beer = new Card('beer', null, 1, null),
            cigar = new Card('cigar', null, 1, null)

      // Bad Cards
      const enemigo = new Card('enemigo', null, -1, null),
            bandito = new Card('bandito', null, null, -1),
            snake = new Card('snake', null, -1, null),
            scorpion = new Card('scorpion', null, -1, null)

      function dealCards() {

      }
```

The expected result would be 16 cards being dealt, each pulling from the card prototype and having its own attributes.

Comment: I think you need to create all the objects you want then just make an array
var goods = [ammo, beer, cigar];
var bads = [enemigo, bandido, snake, scorpion];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest storing instances in an `Array`

Like so:

```
// good cards
const ammoCards = [...Array(4)].map(i => new Card('ammunition', null, 1, null));
const beerCards = [...Array(4)].map(i => new Card('beer', null, 1, null));
// all other good cards
...
const goodCards = [...ammoCards, ...beerCards];

// repeat for bad cards

// and then

const allCards = [...goodCards, ...badCards];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right, you should instantiate inside the deal function.

What I did is write some sort of list with the amount of cards to deal for this each card and the specs of the card.

Then I would loop through each item in the list, and then iterate again with the amount of cards to deal while instantiating the `Card` class given the appropriate specs. I use an array for the specs so I can easily instantiate the Card class with rest parameters.

I made the deal function a method in a class just to keep things consistent. This `Dealer` class that I made can be modified to accept a list of `{specs: [], amount: 0}`. But for now, I'm going to keep it static to keep things simple.

```js
class Card {
    constructor(name, image, health, ammo) {
        this.name = name
        this.image = image
        this.health = health
        this.ammo = ammo
    }
}

class Dealer {
    constructor() {
        this.cards = {};
        this.cards.ammo = { specs: ['ammunition', null, 1, null], amount: 4 };
        this.cards.beer = { specs: ['beer', null, 1, null], amount: 4 };
        this.cards.cigar = { specs: ['cigar', null, 1, null], amount: 2 };
        this.cards.enemigo = { specs: ['enemigo', null, -1, null], amount: 2 };
        this.cards.bandito = { specs: ['bandito', null, null, -1], amount: 2 };
        this.cards.snake = { specs: ['snake', null, -1, null], amount: 2 };
        this.cards.scorpion = { specs: ['scorpion', null, -1, null], amount: 2 };
    }

    deal() {
        const outputCards = [];

        Object.keys(this.cards).forEach(d => {
            for (let i = 0; i < this.cards[d].amount; i++) {
                let c = new Card(...this.cards[d].specs);
                outputCards.push(c);
            }
        });

        return outputCards
    }
}

console.log(new Dealer().deal());
```